# What is the opposite of display = 'none' in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a web page with loading on load-on so when the loading times out and the `<div>` shows. But I am having a bit of trouble with the `.style.display = 'visible'` and I cannot find anything on the opposite of `display = 'none'`. So I am just wondering what is the opposite of 'none' in JS

Comment: There is no "opposite". All the other valid values (block, inline, default, etc) will make the element visible.

Comment: there is also the `visible` style. If you set this to false, the element will take up space but will not be drawn. Obviously, the opposite of visible=false is visible = true or just removing the attribute

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer James posted above is good and I just wanted to elaborate on the values for the display property.

The main values applicable to almost all elements for their `display` property are `block`/ `inline` (there is a small exception like table specific properties).

Certain HTML elements are meant to be rendered on the page as block level elements (think of `<div>, <p>, <h1>` etc), while other elements are naturally meant to sit along-side other elements (think of `<span> <img>` etc). Another way of thinking for me is that `block` level are vertical positioned & `inline` is horizontal.

So, coming round to the answer, the opposite of `display: none` can be either `display: block` / `display: inline`, depending upon the element. I would categorise `block` & `inline` as more of opposite of each other in the layout system. However, that may be thinking in a different context.

Comment: there is also table elements, it can be table/ table-row/ table-cell

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to hide the the loading thing, you use use `visibility: visible` and `visibility: hidden`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using javascript to set the style, the easiest solution is to set an empty display property (`.style.display = '';`) to undo the hiding:

```js
const text = document.getElementById('text-element');

function hide() {
  text.style.display = 'none';
}

function show() {
  text.style.display = '';
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="text-element">Text</span>
</div>

<div>
  <button onclick="hide()">
    Hide Text
  </button>

  <button onclick="show()">
    Show Text
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retain the styling of the element, you could use `.style.display=""`

Using `="block"` or `="inline"` will disrupt your current style.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on which container you are using, it is like saying 'what is the opposite of an invisible living creature.'

[Default display types for html elements](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp)

The opposite of `display: none;` for elements like `<div> <p> <h1> <h2> ...` I would say is `display: block;`.

But then for elements like `<a> <img> <span>` I would say the opposite would be `display: inline;`

Answer (score 0):

There is no "display: visible"

in Jquery you can use .show() and .hide() but in pure vanilla it's understood that any other kind of display besides "none" will show the DOM element.

*ej. display: block, grid, flex, inline, etc.*

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript you can use most of display properties that are available in CSS. Opposite to 
    display="none"

are all the rest of display properties and are used in different situations.

My favorites are:

```
display:table;
```

combined with margin: auto; it aligns child element to the centre very well in most of the situations.

```
display: inline;
```

Displays an element as an inline element like div. Any height and width properties will have no effect

```
display:contents
```

Makes the container disappear, making the child elements children of the element the next level up in the DOM

Comment: These are not the "opposite" of `display: none`. The default behavior of any DOM element is `display: block`, this would be the default opposite of `display: none`.

Comment: @AlexisPhilip the default behavior of any DOM element (also called the initial value) is inline not block (https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#the-display-properties)

Comment: @Temani Afif you are right, my mistake. Most elements are either `inline` or  `block` as [said here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp).